# Is it possible to use both horizontal and vertically tiny scrollbar together

Tags: jquery, tinyscrollbar

I need to have both horizontal and vertical scrolling for large table, I want to use jquery tiny scrollbar for both wise scrolling .Has any one tried using both horizontal and vertically tiny scroll bar together ?? If so pls provide a sample..

Thanks in advance